# deleting a bunch of llvm instructions

Tags: llvm, instructions

I was wondering how we can delete a bunch of instructions in LLVM. 
I tried the following ( based on a post from llvm-dev mailing list )

```
// delete all instructions between [start,end)

void deleteAllInstructionsInRange(Instruction* startInst,Instruction* endInst)
{
    BasicBlock::iterator it(startInst);
    BasicBlock::iterator it_end(endInst);
    it_end--;

    Instruction* currentInst ;

    while(it != it_end )
    {
        currentInst = &*it;

       // this cannot be done at the end of the while loop.
       // has to be incremented before "erasing" the instruction
        ++it;

        if (!currentInst->use_empty())
        {   
            currentInst->replaceAllUsesWith(UndefValue::get(currentInst->getType()));
        }

        currentInst->eraseFromParent();


    }

}
```

**Everything works as expected except for the last iteration.**
Anyone understand why ? ( I've tried using gdb but it gives a segfault error in
the last iteration)

Answer (score 0):

The way your loop is built makes the inner code try to delete what is an invalid iterator: `it == it_end`. A simple `if (it == it_end) continue;` after `it++` will help.

Not sure how LLVM iterables are built, but for the stl containers, `erase` will return an incremented iterator, so you won`t even need the weird loop. A brief look at the [docs](http://www.llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1BasicBlock.html#a8dd327a937563afdb08250abc43820b0) seem to confirm this.